# MySQL order by not ordering

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I got items rated by both ratings, and use an ORDER BY key to order them by positive, but with an example table:

```
//(item)-(pos)-(neg):
item 1 - 50 - 200
item 2 - 24 - 0
item 3 - 15 - 12
```

But item 1 is really less rating than the others, how would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `ORDER BY pos - neg DESC` but it will be slow because it cannot use an index.

You can denormalize your database by explicitly storing the value of `pos - neg` in the table so that you can index it to improve performance. Usually denormalization is regarded as a bad thing and should be avoided but if it the improved performance is required then it is an acceptable approach.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing performance as the only valid reason for using denormalization as a strategy. (I reposted my comment because it was previously poorly worded.)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the net score by subtracting `neg` from `pos`, then order by that net score. Calculate it, then give it an alias, we'll call it `net`:

```
mysql> SELECT item, pos, neg, (pos - neg) AS net
    -> FROM table
    -> ORDER BY net DESC;
+------+-----+-----+------+
| item | pos | neg | net  |
+------+-----+-----+------+
|    2 |  24 |   0 |   24 |
|    3 |  15 |  12 |    3 |
|    1 |  50 | 200 | -150 |
+------+-----+-----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use math in order.

```
ORDER BY pos-neg DESC
```

BUT make sure pos and neg are not UNSIGNED! Because when they try to go negative you will end up with biggest result ever ;)